# map right ctrl key to right click in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have a second CTRL key on my laptop keyboard (thinkpad t450) and I would like to map so it is like a "right click".

Any idea ?

I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You want `xev`, but I'm not sure what you want to do is possible to do without significant manual twiddling of configuration, and it's likely to be fragile...

Comment: Have you tried `xdotool`? It's easier to implement via custom keyboard shortcut in desktop environment.